# Push string into array in struct in solidity

Tags: arrays, function, struct, solidity

I have a struct in solidity defined as follows:

```
struct Batch{
    address payable owner;
    address payable[] precedentsOwners;
    uint[] precedentsBatches;
}
```

I want to create a function that allows me to append a list of owners to this struct, but i get a lot of errors... Is there any way to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `push()` array method to add items into a storage array.

Mind that your array is `address payable` type, so if you're passing a regular `address` (see the argument of `appendToOwners()`), you need to cast it as `payable` first.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    struct Batch{
        address payable owner;
        address payable[] precedentsOwners;
        uint[] precedentsBatches;
    }
    
    Batch public myBatch;
    
    function appendToOwners(address _newOwner) external {
        myBatch.precedentsOwners.push(payable(_newOwner));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Petr! I'll let you know if it worked!

Comment: @Petr Hejda, do you have an idea how to add struct into array of struct and return this from the function? Compiler tells me I can push only on ```storage``` and return from function only ```memory``` or ```calldata```

Comment: @JoeDow Solidity currently doesn't allow resizing in-memory arrays because of how the memory is structured. So you'll need to initialize an empty in-memory array with predefined length and then fill its values. You can find an example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68010807/1693192).